# How to execute JS when page load instead of event trigger?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to come up with a JS that detects number of empty fields in my form. I have 3 fields. If JS counted 2 or more empty fields, JS will change the css color to red. If JS counted 1 empty field, JS will change the css color to green. This works fine when i enter data into the input field. However, when i load the page with data already inside the two fields, the color still remain red. How can make the JS check if there already values in the input box and switch color accordingly based on number of empty fields when the page is loaded?

Below is when the page is loaded but showing red even though there are only 1 empty field.

[image]

I have checked all forums but no answer to my problem

```
'''HTML'''
<table>
<tr></tr><td> Field 1: <input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_fname]" value="1" autofocus/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field 2: <input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_lname]" value="2"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Field 3: <input class="user_field phone" type="text" name="1[user_mobile]"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>

<div class="containerbox">
        <div id="centerbox1" style="background-color: #FF6C60;">
          <div class="value">
          <p><span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">test</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>


'''JS'''
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.user_field').blur(function() {
            var text = "field(s) empty";
        var count = $('.user_field').not(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).length;

        $('#result').html(count + " " + text);

        //*alert(count);

        var udata = count;

        if (udata > 2){
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
        }
        else  
        if (udata <= 2)
        {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
        } 


    });
});
```

I expected the background color to be green as there are 2 data in the fields when the page is loaded but the page shows color red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the function out of the blur event handler, and call it from the `ready()` handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function of its own
  function checkFields() {
    var text = "field(s) empty";
    var count = $('.user_field').not(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).length;

    $('#result').html(count + " " + text);

    //*alert(count);

    var udata = count;

    $('#centerbox1').css('background-color', udata > 2 ? '#FF6C60' : '#99C262');
  }

  // Set up event handler
  $('.user_field').blur(checkFields);

  // Call function
  checkFields();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <td> Field 1: <input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_fname]" value="1" autofocus/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Field 2: <input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_lname]" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Field 3: <input class="user_field phone" type="text" name="1[user_mobile]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>

<div class="containerbox">
  <div id="centerbox1" style="background-color: #FF6C60;">
    <div class="value">
      <p><span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">test</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```